# To arrange items evenly in a container while remembering their original position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to use html and css to make it look like the title.

The requirements are as follows:

- There are one parent element, some child elements, and some grandchild elements.
- The child elements are aligned horizontally in a 6:4 ratio, with equal spacing.
- The grandchildren elements are lined up with equal spacing within them. There are three text boxes on the ratio 6 side and two buttons on the ratio 4 side.
- Multiple grandchild elements may be deleted. In this case, I want to delete the second text box and the first button.
- Even if I delete a grandchild element, I want to keep the other items in their original positions.

(as shown in this figure)
[Figure1: result image that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UYOA.png)
(diagram when elements are deleted)
[Figure2: diagram when elements are deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH55L.png)

Below is the actual code I created.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  flex: 6;
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  flex: 4;
  display: flex;
}

.text-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 10px);
}

.button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 1">
    <input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 2">
    <input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 3">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If Text Box2 is deleted, Text Box1 and 3 will be extended, and if Button1 is deleted, Button2 will be extended by that amount.
I want to leave Text Box1, Text Box3, and Button2 in their original positions, without stretching either element.

I am not a native English speaker, so I am using a translator and it may be difficult to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is not a good solution for this problem. Flex defines how a bunch of elements relate to each other, but there is no way of defining spaces independently of elements.

Grids allow you to do this. A grid’s structure is defined independently of its content elements.

In this case you want an outer `grid` containing two inner grids.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.left, .right {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background: cyan;
}

.right {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background: lime;
}

.text-box, .button {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.t1, .b1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.t2, .b2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.t3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="text-box t1">T1</div>
    <div class="text-box t2">T2</div>
    <div class="text-box t3">T3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="button b1">B1</div>
    <div class="button b2">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="text-box t1">T1</div>
    <div class="text-box t3">T3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="button b2">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to do. I could not come up with a solution in grid due to my lack of study. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would put each `text-box` in a `<div>` then Those `<div>` will have a basis of 100% so that it stretches the `<div class="text-box-wrapper">` and dividing the `left` column into 3 columns of the same length, so in this case, if you want to have 3 columns, you should have 3 different `<div class="text-box-wrapper">`, and if you want to remove a `text-box`, you should only remove the `text-box` inside of the wrapping `<div class="text-box-wrapper">`

Below I show an example, with the left `div`, you could do the same thing to the right `div` to achieve the same results.

This is if you really have to use `flexbox`, if not, I would suggest using `grid` instead as it's more suitable for your use case.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 60%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px
}

.text-box-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.right {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  display: flex;
}

.text-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="text-box-wrapper"><input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 1"></div>
    <div class="text-box-wrapper"><input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 1"></div>
    <div class="text-box-wrapper"><input class="text-box" placeholder="Text Box 1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```